# How do I get the instance from a Generic?

Tags: swift, generics

I just cannot understand why this causes errors (errors shown as comments in code):

```
class SomeClass {
    var id = 123
}

class AnotherClass {
    func myFunc<T>(object: T) {
        T.id = 555 // Error: Type 'T' has no member 'id'
        object.id = 555 // Error: Value of type 'T' has no member 'id'
    }
}

let someClass = SomeClass()
let anotherClass = AnotherClass()
anotherClass.myFunc(someClass)
```

How do you get the instance of someClass after passing it into the generic function?

Also, I can't do any named downcasting inside AnotherClass (as you would expect with a generic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to look up a little bit more about generics. `T` has no member called `id` - that is correct! Just because you pass in *some* T that has a member (SomeClass) that does not matter for the compiler since at some other point you can insert something else like a `Int` or `[Double]` or anything.

Consider adding the following line to your code

```
anotherClass.myFunc(1)
```

What should happen? What should `.id` do??? It would fail because 1 does not have a member called `id`.

Your `T` has no generic constraint telling the compiler anything, therefore it assumes you can just pass in anything. And then you can only use all those properties the possible inputs share.

What you might want to use is for example

```
func myFunc<T : SomeClass>(object: T) {
    object.id = 555
}
```

That tells the compiler that you are only allowed to pass in objects of type `SomeClass` or classes that extend `SomeClass`. Following the logic from above the compiler can look at the code, all possible inputs and allows you to perform the operations that are valid on all possible inputs. Therefore the compiler knows that the `id` property exists since `SomeClass` has it and all classes extending `SomeClass` do as well, since that is how extending works.

*Once again the [apple docs on generics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID179) are a really good place to learn a lot about generics from the basics to the quite complex use-cases.*